# Moving houses with 15 cats

Tags: cats, house-moving

I'm moving houses but I have 15 cats with me whom I want to take to the new house.

All cats are neutered cats and I'm very close to them. Right now they live with us and things are very good but I'm worried. I don't want them to try and escape and get hurt or lost!

I also have a big garden which I want to introduce to them within 2-3 weeks after they get comfortable in their new house.

Any advise please or tips on how to handle my 15 cats :)

Comment: the answers to the linked question gives answers to the moving of cats to a new place.wellcome to pets.

Comment: The linked question is specifically about *outdoor* cats, while this one sounds like it's about indoor cats that the owner would like to give some outdoor access to.  Also, the sheer number might be relevant; I don't know if the technique I used to move 3 cats would work for 15.